# update_option in gateway wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gateway

my gateway name is ( Woocommerce_Add_ZarinPal_Gateway )

i want update title this gateway from code

and this my code

```html
$my_options = get_option('woocommerce_WC_ZPal_settings');
 
$my_options['woocommerce_WC_ZPal_settings']['title'] = 'test';
 
update_option('woocommerce_WC_ZPal_settings', $my_options);
```

but when i update gateway other option with same name is update  / not update plugin gateway name

**my update output :**

woocommerce_WC_ZPal_settings";a:2:{s:5:"title";s:4:"test"}

**orginal plugin output :**

woocommerce_WC_ZPal_settings" string(793) "a:11:{s:11:"base_config";s:0:"";s:7:"enabled";s:3:"yes";s:5:"title";s:35:"پرداخت امن زرین پال";}

> note : i have two ((woocommerce_WC_ZPal_settings)) option with same
> name ! why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found problem , thanks @Pugazhenthi Murugesan .

when i want to update gateway method name from code just must use .

```html
$my_options['title'] = 'test';
 
update_option('woocommerce_bankmellat_settings', $my_options);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to access the **woocommerce_WC_ZPal_settings** in the my_options array.

```
$my_options = get_option('woocommerce_WC_ZPal_settings');

$my_options ['title'] = 'test';
 
update_option('woocommerce_WC_ZPal_settings', $my_options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to find the specific option name that corresponds to the gateway title you want to update

```
$option_name = 'woocommerce_Add_ZarinPal_Gateway_settings';
$my_options = get_option($option_name);
$my_options['title'] = 'test';
update_option($option_name, $my_options);
```

it should update the gateway title for the specific option that you are targeting.